# C# - What is the equivalent [XmlIgnore] for a class?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

This will work

```
public class PleaseIgnoreMe
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string A { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I apply this

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlIgnore]
public class PleaseIgnoreMe
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

the following error shows up.

> Error 265 Attribute 'XmlIgnore' is not valid on this declaration type.
>   It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param, return'
>   declarations.

What is the equivalent [XmlIgnore] for a class ? I need all of its properties to be ignored without specifying it one by one.

Comment: By default, classes and their members are non-serializable

Comment: I am looking for a way to enforce this default.

Comment: That's not what the question title states...also, "I want to declare the entire class as not serializable"

Comment: What would be the point of serialising a class where all properties are ignored?

Comment: The actual case is complicated, but in short, I have classes who use custom serializer. They normally do not get serialized by the standard XmlSerializer. However, when I enable <GenerateSerializationAssemblies> project-wide inside the csproj, these classes get picked up. It causes build error because some of their property names conflict with each other. I can apply [XmlIgnore] to those properties, but they are just too many.